Windows-11 : how to initialize a new SSD disk if it is not visible in Disk Management?
I  connected a new  disk (just bought) to my desktop computer under Windows 11 ( internal Samsung  SSD, 4TB, model:mz-77q4t0bw ).
It appears in Device Manager, with "This device is working properly." shown under  Properties, but in Disk management there is no mention of it.
I see there only Disk 0 and Disk 2, which are conventional hard disks, with volumes in them already, so no Disk 3 appears. The new disk is also visible  when I right-click on any existing disk under  This PC  in  Explorer, Properties, Hardware tab, which lists all three disks connected to this desktop computer, including this new one.  There, on this new disk, I can click the  Properties   button and the Volumes tab correctly does not show any volumes.
How can I initialize the new disk to start adding partitions and volumes to it, given that Disk Management does not show it at all?  I see no error messages. The disk just does not appear in the list.
I run Disk Management elevated as Administrator.
EDIT:
diskpart (elevated ) shows exactly the same information as Disk Management does: both show the same Disk 0 and Disk 2 (online). Interestingly, there is no Disk 1.
(I wonder if  this can be solved from the BIOS setup under Devices / Disks).
Note that this is not a duplicate of some other similar questions out here, which mention some strange error messages. In contrast,  in my case, there are no error messages hinting on a possible problem.

what if you run diskpart in an elevated command prompt, and type list disk - is the disk listed there?

@JaromandaX No, diskpart shows exactly the same information as Disk Managemet does: both show the same Disk 0 and Disk 2 (online). Interestingly, there is no Disk 1. (I shall add this to the question.)

Can this be solved from  the BIOS  setup under Disks? (I cannot try now: I can   connect to that computer only remotely.)

If you disconnect the disk that isn't appearing, do you still have disk 0 and disk 2? or is it then disk 0 and disk 1? Can this be solved from the BIOS setup under Disks? maybe, no idea what your BIOS can do - I did just watch a video where the SATA ports were in IDE mode instead of AHCI, and drives didn't show up, so that could be it

@NickSlash Disk is Samsung SSD 870 QVO 4TB.  Mainboard, can't see now. Shall check when I have physical access.
Maybe i need to install a driver?  Device manager/ Properties/ Driver/ upate says the default driver is the best. I can't find any driver on Samsung's own site. How can I search for it?

The standard windows driver should be fine, have you tried the Samsung disk management tool? (See pvt-tron' answer for the link)

How confident are you in the fact the disk is a legitimate Samsung SSD. The behavior you describe suggests the disk might not actually be a 4TB Samsung SSD. Samsung Magician absolutely supports the SSD you purchase, so if the device is not acting like a legitimate Samsung SSD, that suggests you might have been scammed by the seller.

What is the device category under which the disk appears in device manager?

@Binarus The disk appears under Disk  Drives. (still no mention of it in diskpart or Disk management )

You have assigned the "windows-11" label to your question. However, it seems that the usual methods to partition the drive using Windows do not work (there's not much more to try if diskpart does not show the drive although the device manager does not show issues with the drivers).
Therefore, I would like to suggest to ask for a second opinion and to try whether the drive gets recognized and can be initialized using a different O/S. For example, you could create a bootable USB stick with a Linux system on it to debug the problem further. The following link might serve as a starting point if you want to create a live debian USB stick:
https://www.debian.org/CD/live/index.en.html
Just booting from that live debian will not alter your hard drives in any way. Once you have booted, open a terminal and type:
sudo lsblk -o +model,serial
In the output you should see the problematic drive. If this is not the case, then I am afraid that there's something wrong with the hardware (mainboard, drive) or that you have been scammed (as one of the commenters already has proposed).
If the system tells you that the lsblk command could not be found, you can install it (temporarily, until the next boot) by
sudo apt install util-linux
If you can see your drive in the output of the command mentioned above, please edit your question accordingly (showing the full command's output) and leave a comment. I'll then try to give further instructions about how to initialize the drive under Linux.


You can try to install Samsung Magician (can be found here and is official),
so you can exclude many variables related to the new hardware's well working.

If you don't see the unit in Disk Management, may be a good idea to exchange SATA and power cables with an other device (for an eventual NWME could be tried an other slot) or, if you use a PCIE adapter/controller, a different PCIE slot (full specs of the piece of hw may be useful).
There is also the motherboard or only the controller involved in this issue, may be one of them or (both) need to be configured manually (see motherboard's or eventual onw controller's documentations) or with its software (that may be also searched on internet's official website of the producer); the may that one of them do not support 4TB drives.
Check also if you have connected to a SATA port that belong to a 2nd controller in this case must be enabled in the BIOS and sometimes need a own driver that normally can be found on the Motherboard disk.
As we are talking about a 4TB SSD SATA, we can evaluate the issue by the very large volumes point of view, in fact in Windows the drives larger than 2TB have particular requirements:

must be initialized wit GPT,
UEFI Bios option must be enabled.


more information about:
Microsoft Windows's support rules for drives larger than 2TB can be
red
here
.

The Bios options about very large volumes must be enabled (I think if there is one also LGA Bios option) and may be there are any settings in early Windows versions too.
If the drives installed previously in the PC weren't larger than 1/2TB may be that more than one option, that now are necessary, weren't enabled.
The SSD can be initialized an formatted using an external adapter (exist also a cable-adapter) or also on an other Windows 11 Pro Workstation running on one of latest motherboards (and with a Linux key* or machine too).
